# PersistentFile Upload from NextJS API Route to Django Rest Framework API

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, next.js, file-upload

I have a NextJS app with a form in which the user has to upload an image. This form sends a request to an API Route. In the API Route, I send the fields and the image to the API in Django, but I get this error: `The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.`. The image (path) is an ImageField, and I am using the default `post` method from `ModelViewSet`. I assume it is not an error in the DRF API, as I uploaded images using the the `form-data` tab in Postman and using with Python `requests` library.

In the API Route, I have this code:

```
...
export default async (req, res) => {
if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie ?? '');
        const access = cookies.access ?? false;

        if (access === false) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                error: 'Usuario no autorizado para crear imágenes'
            });
        }

        const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        const formData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
                if (err)reject(err);
                resolve({ fields, files });
            });
        });

        const { path } = formData.files;
        const { nombre, tema } = formData.fields;


        console.log(path); // PersistentFile { ... }
        const newFormData = new FormData();

        newFormData.append('path', path);
        newFormData.append('nombre', nombre);
        newFormData.append('tema', tema);

        try {
            const apiRes = await fetch(`${API_URL}/preguntas/imagenes/`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${access}`,
                },
                body: newFormData
            });

            const data = await apiRes.json();

       ...

};

export const config = {
    api: {
      bodyParser: false,
    },
  };
```

After adding `config`, it seems like I can get all the information submitted in the form (the fields and the image), but when I post the information in the API I get the previous error. `console.log(path)` prints the image as a `PersistentFile`. My question is: How can I fix this? Do I have to transform the image before sending the request to the DRF API?

I tried to transform the image into a blob, but I couldn't fix it. If I write something like this:

```
...
newFormData.append('path', path.path, path.name);
...
```

The error I get is `Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'`, so I think the problem is that I have to transform the `PersistentFile` into a `Blob`, but I don't know how.

Comment: If someone faces the same problem, I have solved it by doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75051091/18475298. Basically, you have to read the file (using the `filepath` field of the PersistentFile).